# Ansible Jinja template variable hostgroup

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I use this template to get list of IPs in hostgroups named [web]

`{% for h in groups['web'] %}
ssh -i ~/ansible_users_keys/{{ new_user_name_global }}_id_rsa {{ new_user_name_global }}@{{ hostvars[h].ansible_nodename }}
{% endfor %}`

Could someone prompt me which variable should I use instead [web] in case if I run this command?

`ansible-playbook -i hosts server.yml --limit web`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

'**ansible_play_batch**' is variablle that has the list of hostnames that apply to the current play.

```
{% for h in ansible_play_batch %}
ssh -i ~/ansible_users_keys/{{ new_user_name_global }}_id_rsa {{ new_user_name_global }}@{{ hostvars[h].ansible_host }}
{% endfor %}
```